# Login using Google in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-signin

I used this below code to create login using google

**background.js**

```
var manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();

        var clientId = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.client_id);
        var scopes = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.scopes.join(' '));
        var redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto');

        var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth' + 
                  '?client_id=' + clientId + 
                  '&response_type=id_token' + 
                  '&access_type=offline' + 
                  '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri + 
                  '&scope=' + scopes;

        var RESULT_PREFIX = ['Success', 'Denied', 'Error'];
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'about:blank'}, function(authenticationTab) {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function googleAuthorizationHook(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
                if (tabId === authenticationTab.id) {
                    var titleParts = tab.title.split(' ', 2);

                    var result = titleParts[0];
                    if (titleParts.length == 2 && RESULT_PREFIX.indexOf(result) >= 0) {
                        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(googleAuthorizationHook);
                        chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);

                        var response = titleParts[1];
                        switch (result) {
                            case 'Success':
                                // Example: id_token=<YOUR_BELOVED_ID_TOKEN>&authuser=0&hd=<SOME.DOMAIN.PL>&session_state=<SESSION_SATE>&prompt=<PROMPT>
                                console.log("suc:"+response);
                            break;
                            case 'Denied':
                                // Example: error_subtype=access_denied&error=immediate_failed
                                console.log("denied:"+response);
                            break;
                            case 'Error':
                                // Example: 400 (OAuth2 Error)!!1
                                console.log("error:"+response);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            chrome.tabs.update(authenticationTab.id, {'url': url});
```

I got this on background console

```
error:id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijc2ZjVhMjk0MWUyZjI0YjBlYzYwZjdmMjE2MWE0MDc1YWM3YzAzNjkifQ.eyJhenAiOiIxNjE5ODU4ODI5NDgtc2FxMDk1dGtpZzBsZ3Bic281dGVnYmd1MTFuNzJuc2guYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiIxNjE5ODU4ODI5NDgtc2FxMDk1dGtpZzBsZ3Bic281dGVnYmd1MTFuNzJuc2guYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMTU1MjM0ODc5OTQ3NDkyNzg1NjUiLCJlbWFpbCI6Imt1c2hhbC5qYWluNjNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImlzcyI6ImFjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE0OTkzNjEzNzEsImV4cCI6MTQ5OTM2NDk3MX0.aBTW7AqRlsnrR9HZhSAid9oU87q0FgcdXqbFpA5PfHQB1s8Cy9GpCYk0Gergom4ZODOG6mDWC2x6DX9sVas6e7b9EhhMeckafhVP5QcdSilK9TcHOfGBYDfw_Jktcf2EIjFAuFirkTyyLiFsXG657jU29k4_Yf7bhPehk8jcj1Jk8Kg-a6vnIO-X6zSc9FXoNUxLjg_KaCcLVa6fR4HqwuzYLKte1ZEzL4S3lsA8TGKsEdpzp15dkCT82w26O6GolA2vpufQ1caKp7zFSC80z0J5Sk2BkBgcTm8PF29TDEv72ImMCYsmqK9rYTd2LCFTizVs_LkE8S3RQ66XvMJHfw&authuser=0&session_state=ecc7aeb026120aac5fc8a18fd1e875b32dc8a52e..e1b4&prompt=consent
```

Here is the screenshot of console which is the result of console.log(tab.title)

[image]

Every time Error switch case is run because tab.title value has Error, but it gives id_token value. So, I need to know why error occurred ?

Is there something missing in this code or wrong ?

And also need to know if I got the success (after your answer) then what to do next to get the user data like email_id and other details.

Comment: What exactly is the value of tab.title when the code runs? What happens if you set a breakpoint inside the callback and step through the code in devtools?

Comment: I edited my question and add what I get in response in switch case of ERROR

Comment: This is not what I was asking.

Comment: Sorry, I also added a screenshot please have a look

Comment: Again, not what I was asking.

Comment: So, I show you tab.title values and what you are looking for now ?

Comment: So which of the shown values are tab.title?

Comment: when I put console.log(tab.title) inside 1st if condition then you will get all the value which shown in the screenshot

Comment: There are lots of values and how do I know which is which? One of the values is `Error` so if it's a tab.title then there is no mystery in the error case being executed.

Comment: Which value you are looking for ? I try to get that value, so my question is why Error is there in the title ? what does it wrong in it ?

Comment: No, your question was `Why error case is run ?` and I've explained that. I also suggested using devtools debugger. Take a look at devtools Network panel too: check the request/response headers and see if there's anything abnormal.